# Pandas: Merge two dataframes with duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Short Question**
Within Pandas, what's the most convenient way to merge two dataframes, such that all entries in the left dataframe receive the first matching value from the right dataframe?

**Longer Question**
Say I have two spreadsheets: `people.csv` and `orders.csv`. `people.csv` contains several columns of information on the person, whereas `orders.csv` contains the person's full name, and a row of the # of orders that person placed.

I need to create a third csv, `output.csv` which contains all of the columns from `people.csv` plus a column from `output.csv` matched on one of the columns within both spreadsheets (called "FULL_NAME" in one, and "CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME" in the other)

`people.csv` is sorted on the FULL_NAME field, but contains duplicate rows, such that there are multiple rows with "John Smith" in the FULL_NAME column. There are also duplicate rows within `orders.csv` but not the same number of duplicates (for example, `people.csv` may have 4 John Smith entries, but `orders.csv` may only have two).

If I use the following code:

```
people = pd.read_csv('people.csv')
orders = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')
full = pd.merge(
    people,
    orders,
    left_on='FULL_NAME',
    right_on='CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME',
)
result.to_csv("output.csv")
```

... I get a CSV where only two of the rows with "John Smith" in the FULL_NAME field has John Smith's number of orders. The rows directly below have no value in that field. That's because `output.csv` only contained two rows with matching values for John Smith, whereas `people.csv` had 4.

Is there a convenient method within Pandas to set the value of one column to the first matching column in the other dataframe, such that all 4 entries contain the first matching value from `orders.csv`?

**EDIT**
Full current version of my script, returning CSVs containing rows not set with the expected values:

```
import pandas as pd

community = pd.read_csv("orders.csv")
full = pd.read_csv("people.csv")
result = pd.merge(
    full,
    community.drop_duplicates(subset=['FULL_NAME'], keep='first'),
    left_on="CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME",
    right_on="FULL_NAME",
    how='left',
)
result.to_csv("output.csv")
```

So I think I'm missing something else here, because some of the rows are matching in the expected way. Here's an example from the ouput file:

```
ID      FULL_NAME   EMPLOYER            DIVISION            ORDER #
7350    John Smith  RiteAid             Clinical Research   25
7351    John Smith  RiteAid             Clinical Research   25
7352    John Smith  Costco              Sales   
7353    John Smith  Costco              Sales
```

This John Smith rows doesn't have a duplicate value within the `orders.csv` file so I do think this is working since two of the rows got it. However, I didn't get a match on the John Smith rows that list Costco rather than RiteAid (or other different fields). This surprises me since I thought the index check was only on the FULL_NAME field.

Any ideas on why the other rows might not be filled in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on `subset=['CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME']` in the `merge` with `how='left'` to keep all rows from `people` such as:

```
full = pd.merge(
    people,
    orders.drop_duplicates(subset=['CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME'], keep='first'), #here the differance
    left_on='FULL_NAME',
    right_on='CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME',
    how='left' #and add the how='left'
)
```

So `orders.drop_duplicates(subset=['CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME'], keep='first')` will contain only once each name and during the `merge`, the matching will be with only this unique name

Comment: Thanks Ben, it's good to know about `drop_duplicates`. Unfortunately, this doesn't get me quite there: with this, now only the first of the 4 John Smith rows contains the order # column. Is there a way to make all 4 matched rows have the value from the deduped orders dataframe?

Comment: @RobertTownley even with the parameter `how='left'`? I added after I forgot at first

Comment: Thanks Ben, just edited with more info. The how='left' and deduping do seem to be working, but it's not matching consistently off of the FULL_NAME field. Instead, it seems like only the rows that were identical duplicates in the `people.csv` sheet are both receiving data, whereas rows that had differences on fields other than `FULL_NAME` are being treated as different entities. Does that seem to be what's going on to you as well?

Comment: @RobertTownley indeed the behavior you get is not expected. Like this, I don't see any reason why it would not work like expected. Could you add the relevant rows from both `full` and `community` dataframes to see if I can reproduce the behavior?

Comment: HI Ben I tried to reproduce a simple example, but wasn't able to make my issue come up. I think there's something off about my CSVs, which I'll need to look into further. But you're right that, with clean data, your approach does exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @RobertTownley ok hope you find what's going on. You can try a [`full['FULL_NAME'].str.strip()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) or something equivalent. You may have "hidden" space at the beginning/end of the names in your data!

Comment: Dropping back in to say that it was indeed a whitespace issue, and removing the spacing worked, so this does do what I had hoped